# How to use quill-image-drop-module in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quill, vue-quill-editor

I use [vueup/vue-quill](https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill) for Vue 3 and want to use [kensnyder/quill-image-drop-module](https://github.com/kensnyder/quill-image-drop-module).

This is my code :

**Main.js**

```
import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill';
import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';
import Quill from 'quill';
import { ImageDrop } from 'quill-image-drop-module';
Quill.register('modules/imageDrop', ImageDrop)

createApp(App).component('QuillEditor', QuillEditor).mount('#app')
```

**Editor.vue**

```
<template>
  <QuillEditor :modules="modules" theme="snow" />
</template>

<script>
  import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill';
  import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';

  export default {
    components: {
      QuillEditor,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        modules: {
          imageDrop: true,
        },
      };
    }
  }
</script>
```

If I run the code above, I got an error :

[image]

How to fix this error?

Are quill-image-drop-module works on Vue 3?

Comment: Did you managed to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Provide to `<QuillEditor>` a prop called toolbar (ex. `toolbar='minimal'`).
vue-quill is creating options for Quill and only when `toolbar` prop is present it creates an object key `modules` that it uses to register other modules.